# Ошибка Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php

Перешел на другой хостинг и вылазеет следующая ошибка.

> Creating default object from empty value

Вот код

```
$gallery_guest= $this->pages_model->getProductGallery_guest($id);

        if(!$gallery_guest){
            $gallery_guest[0]->img= "/images/no-image.png";
        }
```

Ошибка вот на этой строчке.

```
$gallery_guest[0]->img= "/images/no-image.png";
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте на

```
if(!$gallery_guest){
    $gallery_guest[0]["img"]= "/images/no-image.png";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так же можно было сделать вот так $gallery_guest[0] = new stdClass();